# renderer.setElementStyle “Cannot set property 'background-color'

Tags: angular

I'm learning angular and I am trying to set background color using _renderer.setElementStyle but its not apply can some one help me please

```
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private render: Renderer) { }

  @HostListener("mouseover") onmouseover() {
    this.changeTextColor("red");
  }

    @HostListener("mouseleave") onmouseleave() {
    this.changeTextColor("blue");
  }

  changeTextColor(color: string) {
    this.render.setElementStyle(this.elementRef.nativeElement,"background-color",color);
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsm9ii?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: You can see something similar here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39023277/angular2-renderer-setelementstyle-is-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default a component element has an inline display style. You should change this to a block style using the css:

```
:host {
  display: block;
}
```

this will make the [stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b7nsfs?file=src/app/app.component.css) work.

On the other hand, the [`Renderer`](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer) is deprecated, and at the time of writing, one should use the [`Renderer2`](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2), which has the setStyle method

On the other other hand, using the Renderer for such a task should not be done. Mainly, you should never use renderer, unless you somehow cannot access the elements otherwise. For instance if they are injected through a 3rd party library.

I understand that you are trying out angular, but just to make it a full answer, best way to handle this is to use the `@HostBinding()` and either a style or class binding. This still does not take away the necessity of making it a block element. So perhaps it's better to attach `bgColor` to a block element inside the components template:

```
@HostBinding('style.backgroundColor')
bgColor: string = 'blue';

@HostListener("mouseover") onmouseover() {
  this.bgColor = "red";
}

@HostListener("mouseleave") onmouseleave() {
  this.bgColor = "blue";
}
```